# Not able to construct proper header for groovy function Get request

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Writing my first function here for Groovy native lib and running into an issue. A method to get Github Labels for pull-requests. @param github_token String token with permission to access and read PR information.

`getLabelsPerPullRequest.groovy: 19: expecting '}', found ':' @ line 19, column 28. 'Authorization': 'token '+ github_token, ^`

Here is my function

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper 

def getLabelsPerPullRequest(String github_token) {
    
    def labels

    def scmHead = jenkins.scm.api.SCMHead.HeadByItem.findHead(currentBuild.rawBuild.getParent())
    def repo = scmHead.getSourceRepo()
    def prId = scmHead.getId()

    if(github_token && github_token != null) {
        // Set the call headers with Oauth token.
        def headers = "{'Authorization': 'token '+ ${github_token},'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json'}"
        // Construct request number URL in Github
        def pr_url = "https://github.optum.com/api/v3/repos/SOP-Bot/${repo}/pulls/${prNbr}"

        def json = sh(
                        script: "curl -X Get ${pr_url} -H ${headers}",
                        returnStdout: true
        )                
        def prInfo = JsonOutput.toJson(text: json)
        labels = prInfo.labels
    }
    return labels
}
```

Comment: Why are you using curl instead of performing this request within groovy?

Comment: Its my first function so not sure if their is a standard way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each header needs to be a separate -H argument.  You can do something like this.  I added -s to curl because you probably don't want the extra progress output but it may not actually be an issue.

```
def headers = [
    "-H 'Authorization: token ${gitub_token}'",
    "-H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json'"
]
...
def json = sh(
    script: "curl -s -X GET ${headers.join(' ')} '${pr_url}'",
    returnStdout: true
)
```